# Rest assured: How change value in header?

Tags: java, rest-assured

My test case uses two roles (user_1, user_2).
During the test case I need change user_1 to user_2.
I try to replace jwt token in authorization header for user_2, but I get behavior like this:

```
@BeforeAll
static public void beforeAll() {

RestAssured.requestspecification = new RequestSpecBuilder()
.addHeader("Authorization": "jwt token for user_1")
.build();
}

@Test
public void test() {

...test running with user_1...

RestAssured.requestspecification = new RequestSpecBuilder()
.addHeader("Authorization": "jwt token for user_2")
.build();

...test running with user_2...
}
```

and I see Authorization header has duplicate

```
StackRace:
"Authorization": "jwt token for user_1"
"Authorization": "jwt token for user_2"
```

And the moment I have now idea

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#header-mergingoverwriting), try something like:

```
RestAssured.requestspecification = new RequestSpecBuilder()
.setConfig(RestAssuredConfig.config().headerConfig(headerConfig().overwriteHeadersWithName("Authorization")
.addHeader("Authorization": "jwt token for user_2")
.build();
```